# ¿Cómo resolver este java.net.SocketTimeoutException usando easyModbus?

Tags: java, modbus

Estoy intentando de utilizar la librería easyModbus para hacer un programa que lea de estos registros en Java, he utilizado esta librería antes en .Net sin problemas pero en Java nada más iniciar el programa me manda esta excepción:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at de.re.easymodbus.modbusclient.ModbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(ModbusClient.java:920)
    at pruebaMod.main.main(main.java:14)
```

Este es mi código, es el de ejemplo que viene en la pagina de [easyModbus](http://easymodbustcp.net/en/)  y la gente utiliza sin problemas

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
       ModbusClient modbusClient = new ModbusClient("127.0.0.1", 502);
        try
        {
            modbusClient.Connect();
            System.out.println(modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(0, 10)); 

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
         e.printStackTrace();
        } 
}
```

Estoy haciendo de servidor con el simulador [mod_RSsim](https://sourceforge.net/projects/modrssim/) el cual he utilizado antes sin problemas. Gracias.

Comment: Pues si hay un readtimeout, posiblemente algo esté bloqueando la comunicación con tu simulador. Revisa que ni el antivirus ni ningún otro software de seguridad esté atrapando las respuestas del simulador

Comment: He revisado antivirus y firewall y todo el tema de seguridad pero nada sigue igual, no se donde puede estar el fallo

Comment: Revisa que el simulador haya iniciado correctamente. Revisa el Visor de Eventos de Windows para ver que no haya errores al iniciarlo o al arrancar tu cliente

Comment: nada el simulador funciona correctamente, firewall y antivirus desactivado y sigue con el mismo error, no queda ningún registro en el visor de eventos, y si pruebo el programa con el mismo simulador pero escrito en c# con la misma librería si que funciona,pero si es en java con netbeans o eclipse nada misma excepción, podría ser algún tema de java que pueda configurar? Queda decir que si es con otro ordenador si que funciona pero si es con una maquina virtual de ubuntu en virtual box con adaptador puente, lo que sería como otro pc, salta la misma excepción... Es muy raro...

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizar el Modbus Slave, a mi nunca me ha dado problemas.

[image: Comunicación exitosa NetBeans to Modbus TCP]

Comment: Gracias lo probaré

Comment: Hola Rogelio, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento del sitio (y con ello ganarás una nueva medalla). Considera editar tu respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué hace ModBus Slave? ¿cómo se usaría en el caso de la pregunta? ¿cómo resolvería el problema? Saludos.